# Cannot find cause of custom program error: 0x28

Tags: anchor, solana-program, token

I'm stuck in this error forever:
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0x28

Problem is here.

Firstly implemented my program with using anchor 0.27.0 and below is code. It's part of account struct that pay 2 specific token and mint NFT.

```
/***************** ACCOUNTS FOR TRANSFER TOKEN *****************/
     #[account(mut)]
     pub from_ata: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
 
     // user send 2 TOKEN to original TOKEN wallet
     #[account(
        token::authority = Pubkey::from_str("PROGRAM_ADDRESS").unwrap()
    )]
    //  #[account(mut)]
     pub to_ata: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
/*************************************************************/
```

And it worked correctly.

Time passed, and I had to update anchor from 0.27.0 to 0.29.0.

Editing code and test progressed normally until yesterday, but above code occurs 0x28 error.

Below code is my current edited code.

```
/***************** ACCOUNTS FOR TRANSFER TOKEN *****************/
     #[account(mut)]
     pub from_ata: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
 
     // user send 2 TOKEN to original TOKEN wallet
     #[account(
        token::mint = Pubkey::from_str("TOKEN_ADDRESS").unwrap(), 
        token::authority = Pubkey::from_str("PROGRAM_ADDRESS").unwrap()
    )]
    //  #[account(mut)]
     pub to_ata: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
/*************************************************************/
```

And here's part of error log.

```
'Program log: IX: Sign Metadata',
'Program log: This creator address was not found',
'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 11940 of 330803 compute units',
'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x28',
'Program GpT3urUpRFHTw2NHMiv6YzygkGm6EQcLEG4aVwdQWjwk consumed 280987 of 599850 compute units',
'Program GpT3urUpRFHTw2NHMiv6YzygkGm6EQcLEG4aVwdQWjwk failed: custom program error: 0x28'
```

Both googling and error cheat sheet don't work for me.

I tried everything I can but still my code doesn't work.

What did I do wrong and what should I do?

Comment: 0x28 isn't a valid anchor error so this comes from the program, maybe from the Transfer program but impossible to tell without the error log.

Comment: @Whiteseal Thank your for reply. I added some error log.

Answer (score 2):

PROBLEM SOLVED it was about metaplex error.

```
'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x28',
```

Looking up 0x28 in metaplex errors.rs shows the cause.